# Tensorflow scope problems

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow

Why does this piece of code not work and throw the error:

```
ValueError: Variable model/conv1/weights does not exist, or was not created with tf.get_variable(). Did you mean to set reuse=None in VarScope?
```

This was copied from https://www.tensorflow.org/programmers_guide/variables

Generally every time I try to run code with scopes it always throws me this error, and I don't understand what's going on. I read through the scope tutorial but honestly it's really confusing to me. It would be awesome if someone could shed some light on what's going on.

```
import tensorflow as tf

def conv_relu(input, kernel_shape, bias_shape):
    # Create variable named "weights".
    weights = tf.get_variable("weights", kernel_shape,
        initializer=tf.random_normal_initializer())
    # Create variable named "biases".
    biases = tf.get_variable("biases", bias_shape,
        initializer=tf.constant_initializer(0.0))
    conv = tf.nn.conv2d(input, weights,
        strides=[1, 1, 1, 1], padding='SAME')
    return tf.nn.relu(conv + biases)

input1 = tf.random_normal([1,10,10,32])
input2 = tf.random_normal([1,20,20,32])

def my_image_filter(input_images):
    with tf.variable_scope("conv1"):
        # Variables created here will be named "conv1/weights", "conv1/biases".
        relu1 = conv_relu(input_images, [5, 5, 32, 32], [32])
    with tf.variable_scope("conv2"):
        # Variables created here will be named "conv2/weights", "conv2/biases".
        return conv_relu(relu1, [5, 5, 32, 32], [32])

with tf.variable_scope("model"):
  output1 = my_image_filter(input1)
with tf.variable_scope("model", reuse=True):
  output2 = my_image_filter(input2)
```

Comment: Your code runs fine on my machine (tf v1.8). What version are you using?

Comment: Ahh I didn't realize this was a version issue. It installed 1.1.0 for me initially, and I upgraded and now it works. Thank you!